# Deleting rows on protected sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet that is protected; all cells are locked besides those that are intended to be edited by the user. I would like the user to be able to delete rows, so I enabled 'delete rows' when protecting my sheet. As expected I receive the error message "You are trying to delete a row that contains a locked cell..." I understand why this is happening as all cells outside the area I expect user input are locked.

I don't want to unlock all other cells as I don't want users to enter data in them.

I have researched the ability unprotect the sheet on a 'delete row' event but wasn't able to find such an event. I guess I can add a button next to each row that unprotects the sheet deletes the row and reprotects the sheet but was hoping for a more elegant/easier solution.

How can I delete a row in a protected sheet when there are locked cells in the columns to the right of my table?

Comment: You can code a script for that... insert a button that deletes selected rows and the code will unprotect the sheet, delete the rows and protect the sheet again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can normally achieve this via the following code:

```
Public Sub ProtectMySheet()
    Sheet1.Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
End Sub
```

However, I've discovered this to be hit or miss sometimes. So I sometimes do this

```
Public Sub EditStuffInProtectedSheet()

    With Sheet1

        .Unprotect MYPASSWORD ' You can store your password in a safe location, or make it a constant (if you're okay with your End Users knowing it)
        ' ***Do Stuff***
        .Protect MYPASSWORD

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have a button which calls a VBA function which does the deleting. And use

```
Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
```

when protecting the sheet.This way you'll be able to delete rows and perform other actions via VBA on a protected sheet.